# array of objects

Tags: java, list, iterator

i have a problem with my script

i have a method that return a card, another return the name, another the value and another the suit

```
public Card pickRandomCard() {
        while (rand < 6) {
        System.out.println(deckOfCards.get(rand));
        int cardValuePlayer1 = (deckOfCards.get(rand).toInt());
        currentTotal1 = cardValuePlayer1;
        String name1 = (deckOfCards.get(rand).toString());
        nameF = name1;
        String suit_1 = (deckOfCards.get(rand).suit());
        suit1 = suit_1; 
        return deckOfCards.get(rand++);
    }
        return null;

    }

    public int totalValuePlayer1() {
        return currentTotal1;
    }

    public String name1() {
        return nameF;
    }

    public String suit_1() {
        return suit1;
    }
```

but now, i want to create an arraylist of cards, like a hand of cards, so my ideia is create an arraylist with 5 cards, but if i did something like

```
    List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(); 
    Iterator<Card> iter = hand.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        hand.add(gr.pickRandomCard());
    }
```

i receive Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0

i have this code in another class to call each method, suit, value of card, image, but i need to create a list to compare cards, and with the code below, it is impossible to compare a card one by one

```
    ActionListener one = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (gr1.getCounter1() < 5) {
                gr1.setCounter1(gr1.getCounter1() + 1);
                test1.setIcon(play1a);
                pn1.setText(Integer.toString(play2a));
                pn5.setText(play3a);
                pn50.setText(play4a);
            } else {
                pn5.setText("No more cards");
            }
        }
    };

    arraybtn[1].addActionListener(one);
    arraybtn[1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));

    play1a = gr.pickRandomCard().getImage();
    play2a = gr.totalValuePlayer1();
    play3a = gr.name1();
    play4a = gr.suit_1();

    arraybtn[1].setText(play3a);//change the name of button
```

i think the problem is that i need to create 4 list, each for correspondent method (suit, image, value), but i don't have any idea how i can do that

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there is a flaw:

```
// this iterates over existing cards
Iterator<Card> iter = hand.iterator();

// but there are no cards yet
while (iter.hasNext() /* this will never return true */ ) {
    // so this is never executed
    hand.add(gr.pickRandomCard());
}
```

Try this instead:

```
List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    hand.add(gr.pickRandomCard());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(); 
 Iterator<Card> iter = hand.iterator();

 while (iter.hasNext()) {
     hand.add(gr.pickRandomCard());
 }
```

Your "hand" is empty, therefore you have no elements. That's why your size is 0;

Also you can create a new class, say Playa, that has name, suit, image, value attributes.

Comment: You probably mean `Player`. `Playa` would have attributes like sand, ocean, palm trees,etc :-)

Comment: @Sean don't be a Playa-Hater ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
        hand.add(gr.pickRandomCard());
    }
```

iter is from the empty list you just created so hasNext() will always return false;

You are mentioning concepts like suit and hand but already deciding they should be ArrayLists. Why don't you create Suit and Hand classes. Hand will probably contains some collection of cards and a construtor or method that populates it. Suit should be an enum like

```
enum Suit{
  CLUBS,
  SPADES,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS
}
```

If you model your data correctly in an OO fashion you'll find your code easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Sean's answer, the reason why you can't iterate your `hand` ArrayList is because it doesn't have any items. So you need to use a for loop to add them.